# Is there any relationship between model's clean() method and form's clean() method?

Tags: python, django

I have overwritten `clean()` methods for some of my models to construct constraints to meet my DB schema requirements (Because it required runtime information for those validations).

Since now I have finished most of the back-end side components(*models*, *signals*, ..) now I'm trying to write `ModelForm`s for my  models.

What I'm wondering is that, is there any relationship between the `clean()` method of model and `clean()` implementation on the form side?

If so and form's `clean()` calls model's `clean()` I won't have to rewrite my model - side `clean()` implementation and be able to avoid code redundancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `ModelForm` cleaning involves model cleaning. That's the idea with a `ModelForm`: there are *a lot* of useful defaults that can be determined by auto building a form object from a model.

I've discovered this clean chaining through personal experience, but to back it up I can reference the source.

On 1.8, `ModelForm`s call the model instance `full_clean` method. On 1.7, it calls the `clean` method directly.

### Form.full_clean()

```
def full_clean(self):
    # ..... snip
    self._clean_fields()
    self._clean_form()
    self._post_clean()
```

### ModelForm._post_clean for 1.8

Model `full_clean()` calls `clean()` amongst other validation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/

```
self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
```

### ModelForm._post_clean for 1.7

```
self.instance.clean()
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [`Model.clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) and `ModelForm`s [`clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method), I don't think there is any relationship between them.

These two `clean` has the same name but they did a different job.

`Model.clean` is used to validate the data you are going to store into database, and make sure the data is ok and can be stored into database.

> This method should be used to provide custom model validation, and to modify attributes on your model if desired.

`ModelForm`s `clean`, by my understanding, is to validate what the user has entered, and make sure they are ok.

> You can override the clean() method on a model form to provide additional validation in the same way you can on a normal form.

And on a normal form, it's:

> Implement a clean() method on your Form when you must add custom validation for fields that are interdependent.

And I think [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean) one is also what you wanted:

> Notice that we are talking about the clean() method on the form here, whereas earlier we were writing a clean() method on a field. It’s important to keep the field and form difference clear when working out where to validate things. Fields are single data points, forms are a collection of fields.